# Shinydashboard, Server.R does not compile "source"-lines

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on a Shiny-app and since it is a rather large project, I am splitting it up in several files.

I have these app.R, ui.R and server.R:
app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

header <- dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs", 
              sidebarMenuOutput("menu"))
)
MainBox <- fluidRow(
  titlePanel("PromView"), 
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab1", QuickPlot()),
    tabItem(tabName = "tab2", p("Doorloop Content"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(MainBox)

ui <- dashboardPage(title = "PromView", skin = "blue",
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

server.R

```
library(plotly)

source("~/Werk/BigData/Process Mining/R/PM_Globals.R", local = TRUE)

source("~/Werk/BigData/Process Mining/PromView/PromView/QuickFacts.R", local = TRUE)
source("~/Werk/BigData/Process Mining/PromView/PromView/LoadData.R", local = TRUE)
source("~/Werk/BigData/Process Mining/PromView/PromView/Filters.R", local = TRUE)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Quick facts", tabName = "tab1"),
      menuItem("Doorloop",    tabName = "tab2")
    )
  })
  isolate({updateTabItems(session, "tabs", "tab1")})
}
```

When I start the app (in Rstudio), the app complains that it can' t find the QuickPlot()-function. The environment-pane in Rstudio is empty.

When I manually execute the "source"-lines in server.R, the environment-pane shows that all data are loaded and that functions are defined. The app then starts normally.

How can I force shiny to use the " source"-lines?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can put the "source"-lines in the ui.R file, shiny loads ui file before server file and therefore, your app will complain that there is no QuickPlot function.